# Copying gif from a gridview and pasting into a text message in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview of gifs that I am displaying, and I want the user of the app to be able to select one and have it copied and saved into the user's clipboard so they could paste it manually into a text message. Right now, I am attempting to do this by referencing the gif as a Uri and putting the Uri into the Clipboard. I got my code to work using a string of text, but I cannot get it to copy the Uri of a gif. I am unsure where I am off, as I could be just referencing the Uri incorrectly, or going about it completely wrong. 
Heres the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


        copy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.copy);
        copy.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View gridview){
        Uri copyUri =       Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.eric.hellogridview/drawable/broke");
        ClipData theClip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "broke",     copyUri);
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)     getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(theClip);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied to Clipboard",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid to tell you it's impossible. 
You can copy the image to phons external memory and let the user to access it from there.
There is an option to build for spesific manufactors who useing hidden API, But its seem to be too complicated and nasty.